# Add new string to resource string array dynamically

Tags: android, string, android-arrayadapter, arrays

Im making workout log and i want that ther user will be able to add new exercise types.

I made string array in the resources and a spinner that will take the strings from the string array in the resources.

Im not sure how to add new string to resources string array from java code.
I tried this code, but i get exception.

thanks for helping :)

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.setNewExercise:
        String[] exerciseStringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.exerciseTypes);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.exerciseTypes, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        String exerciseCheck = addNewExercise.getText().toString();
        try{
        for (int i = 0; i < exerciseStringArray.length; i++)
        {
            if (exerciseCheck.equals(exerciseStringArray[i]))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This exercise already exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
            else if (i == exerciseStringArray.length - 1 && exerciseCheck.equals(exerciseStringArray[i]) == false)
            {
                list.add(exerciseCheck);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
        }catch(Exception e){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wtf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Ive tried now this code, and my spinner is loaded empty and i get force closed when trying to save new string.

```
    /////////////////////Exercise spinner/////////////////////
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    list = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
    exerciseAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, R.array.exerciseTypes, list);

    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    exerciseAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    workOutChoose.setAdapter(exerciseAdapter);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.setNewExercise:


        String exerciseCheck = addNewExercise.getText().toString();

        try{

            if (exerciseAdapter.getPosition(exerciseCheck) >= 0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This exercise already exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                exerciseAdapter.add(exerciseCheck);
                exerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wtf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify the resources themselves. You are welcome to convert your `String[]` into an `ArrayList<String>` and add in additional strings, obtained from elsewhere (e.g., file, database, `SharedPreferences`) if you wish.

`add()` on an `ArrayAdapter` works if the `ArrayAdapter` was made from an `ArrayList`, not a Java array (`[]`), as a Java array's size cannot be changed at runtime.

Comment: @tomer: This free excerpt from my book covers the use of `ArrayAdapter`: http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf

Comment: looks nice, thanks.
@CommonsWare: I posted new code, and still got error...
can you please take a look at him?

Comment: @tomer: Look at LogCat and examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash. BTW, you do not need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after `add()`, as `add()` does that for you automatically. If you need further assistance, please post a new StackOverflow question with the code, the stack trace, and an indication of what lines of code are referred to in that stack trace.